# Webpack with multiple html/js/css files for multiple pages to multiple directories

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler

I have a project setup which looks like the following:

**Project**

- data

  - public

    - pages

      - main -- > need an html bundle here
      - settings -- > need an html bundle here
      - admin -- > need an html bundle here
- frontEnd

  - public

    - pages

      - main

        - scripts
        - styles
        - html
      - settings

        - scripts
        - styles
        - html
      - admin

        - scripts
        - styles
        - html

I'm working inside the **frontEnd** folder and i want to bundle my files to the data folder.

I can't figure out how to do that.

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file

```
const path = require('path');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// npm run build for packing everything

const dataPath = "/data/public/pages/";
const frontEndPath = "/frontEnd/public/pages/";

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, ''),
    mode: "production",
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    experiments: {
        topLevelAwait: true
    },
    entry: {
        '/data/public/pages/main/bundle/main.bundle': '/frontEnd/public/pages/main/scripts/main.js',
        '/data/public/pages/settings/bundle/settings.bundle': '/frontEnd/public/pages/settings/scripts/settings.js',
        '/data/public/pages/admin/bundle/admin.bundle': '/frontEnd/public/pages/admin/scripts/admin.js',
        '/data/public/pages/builder/bundle/builder.bundle': '/frontEnd/public/pages/builder/scripts/builder.js',
        '/data/public/pages/editor/bundle/editor.bundle': '/frontEnd/public/pages/editor/scripts/editor.js',
        '/data/public/pages/login/bundle/login.bundle': '/frontEnd/public/pages/login/scripts/login.js',
        '/data/public/pages/hardwares/bundle/hardwares.bundles': '/frontEnd/public/pages/hardwares/scripts/hardwares.js',
        '/data/public/pages/graphs/bundle/graphs.bundle': '/frontEnd/public/pages/graphs/scripts/graphs.js',
        '/data/public/pages/welcomeSetup/bundle/welcomeSetup.bundle': '/frontEnd/public/pages/welcomeSetup/scripts/main.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, ''),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin(),
    ],
    optimization: {
        chunkIds: 'total-size',
        mergeDuplicateChunks: true,
        minimize: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            assets: '/frontEnd/public/assets/',
        },
    }
};
```

With this config file i can bundle the different js files into their corresponding folders but i must copy / paste the rest to the data folder like my css files and the html file.

I have tried `HtmlWebpackPlugin` without success like this

```
const path = require('path');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

let htmlPages = [
    {
        name:"main/index",
        script: '/frontEnd/public/pages/main/scripts/main.js'
    },
];
let multipleHtmlPlugins = htmlPages.map(page => {
  return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: `/frontEnd/public/pages/${page.name}.html`,
    filename: `${page.name}.html`,
    chunks: [`${page.script}`]
  })
});

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CompressionPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      chunks: ['main']
    })
  ].concat(multipleHtmlPlugins),
};
```

Somehow i need to create a html file where my bundled js file is included as well as my css files. Everything zipped.

Is this possible? And if so, how? Let me know if i left out any detail.